Angular import errors in Visual Studio Code despite correct paths and dependencies
I am working on an Angular project in Visual Studio Code. The import paths are correctly configured, and the project compiles and runs without any errors in both the frontend and backend. However, Visual Studio Code marks the imports as incorrect, showing messages like:
"Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations"enter image description here
What I Have Tried So Far:
Verified that the import paths exist and are correct in the project structure.
Reinstalled all dependencies (node_modules) using npm install.
Cleared npm cache with npm cache clean --force.
Restarted the TypeScript Server in Visual Studio Code ("TypeScript: Restart TS Server").
Deleted Angular cache using rm -rf .angular/cache.
Reinstalled the Angular Language Service extension.

There is nothing to do with node packages. Do as follow,

Delete all non angular import statements ( import {CamaraComponent} from 'src/app/components/camara.camara.component').
Now you will get error in CamaraComponent instance.
Right click on that and chose Quick fix and select import
So VS Code will auto import the file based on your folder structure.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

it'll be relative to the current path.  You probably need something like: from '../services/your-service.service'  but it'll depend on your directory structure.  Use ".." for up one level/folder, use just "./" for same level/folder.  Or use @Jilo Cleetus's method to have the IDE resolve.
